# Answering two questions to proceed further

Tags: php

I was trying to build a simple php page in which the user is answering two questions to proceed further. My code is :

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['answer1']) OR $_POST['answer1'] != "blue")
   {
   ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>What color is the sky ?</p>
    <input type="text" name="answer1">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </p>
   <?php }
   else {
      if (!isset($_POST['answer2']) OR $_POST['answer2'] != "white")
    {
    ?>
       <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>What color is the milk ?</p>
        <input type="text" name="answer2">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </p>
    <?php }
    else {
        echo 'Congratulation !';
    }
  }
```

?>

When answering to the first question, the second is displayed. But when answering to the second one, it is getting me back to the first question and not showing the congratulation message.
Can someone tell me what is going wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because `$_POST['answer1']` is not set. So your first condition is true and your code will never reach the`else`.

Comment: OK, and what would be the solution ? The nested if/else I used cannot be used like this ?

Comment: I've added an answer where you have to change your if/else clauses a little bit (always start with the strongest one first)

Answer (score 0):

Your script will never reach the `else` block because the variable values aren't stored permanently. You'll need to use sessions, or introduce a different way to solve this issue.

If you want to do it with a single page, you can add both the input fields in same page, and then forward the user only if both the answers are correct.

The best method, in my opinion, would be to use a captcha instead.

Comment: Of course I have other solution. I can use multiple php page. But I wanted to do it in a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake its common , its a logical error:

In the first IF statetment u ask if the POST answer1 dosent exist or if its blue.

But .. when u subbmit the 2nd form that request doesnt have setted the answer1 , so .. its back to the first if ..

Your solution its simple:

```
 else {
  if (!isset($_POST['answer2']) OR $_POST['answer2'] != "white")
{
?>
   <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>What color is the milk ?</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="answer1" value="blue"> <--- add this line to skip the first if uin the second submit
    <input type="text" name="answer2">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </p>
<?php }
else {
    echo 'Congratulation !';
}
```

Comment: Great it works! Thank you!.. Can I use this when I want to use more questions to reach the final goal or is it not recomanded and it is better to use another method ?

Comment: the best way to doit its add a hidden field for the step, so in the IF's u just add a if($_POST["step"] == 1 && ... and set  the hidden value with the step where u r .

Answer (score 0):

This Works
just add a hidden field in second form

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['answer1']) OR $_POST['answer1'] != "blue")
   {
   ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>What color is the sky ?</p>
    <input type="text" name="answer1">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </p>
   <?php }
   else {
      if (!isset($_POST['answer2']) OR $_POST['answer2'] != "white")
    {
    ?>
       <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>What color is the milk ?</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="answer1" value="blue">
        <input type="text" name="answer2">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </p>
    <?php }
    else {
        echo 'Congratulation !';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your form structure change your if/else clauses:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['answer2']) && $_POST['answer2'] == "white")
    {
        echo 'Congratulation !';
    } else if((isset($_POST['answer1'] && $_POST['answer1'] == "blue") || (isset($_POST['answer2'] && $_POST['answer2'] != "white"))
    { ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>What color is the milk ?</p>
        <input type="text" name="answer2">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>What color is the sky ?</p>
        <input type="text" name="answer1">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
!isset($_POST['answer1']) OR $_POST['answer1'] != "blue"
```

to this:

```
(!isset($_POST['answer1']) OR $_POST['answer1'] != "blue") && !isset($_POST['answer2'])
```

adding answer2 as a requirement to not be set in the first conditional will make it pass to the next one when the second form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass a third check variable such as:

```
if(isset($_POST['completed'] && $_POST['completed'] == true){ 

    echo "Congratulations";
    exit();
}
```

Put that above the other statements so it's the first thing checked.